# Vue server side events and showing components

Tags: vue.js, events, vuex

How can I use server side events(sse) in vue? I'm receiving sse from backend and I need to implement that when I receive first event, I will show ringing panel on screen. Then I can accept that call and then show different panel and when I click on hang up I will show again screen like before events. It will be a call centrum.
I created method for receieving and handling event.

```
setupStream(){
   let evtSource = new EventSource('/hzs/events.sse')

   evtSource.addEventListener('call_status', event => {
      let data = JSON.parse(event.data)
      this.channels.push(data);
   }, false)
}
```

Now, when I call I get something like this:

[image: Response]

Where first curly brackets are incoming call, second are after I pick up phone and last are after I hang up.

How can I use this in app and show for example green ringing bar on screen based on events? So for every event I need different UI components.

Do I need to use vuex?

Thanks

Comment: depends on the complexity of the system, i.e how you intend to handle multiple calls at once. but it essentially boils down to setting a *state* model of sorts (could be in vuex) which then you simply do `v-if="channel.ringing"` on a component. what are you stuck on?

Comment: Until now I did not needed vuex, so I will implement that and then If something I will ask again

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I created vuex file but how can I access that sse data? where should I put evtSource.addEventListener in vuex? I am new to vuex